# DISPLAY Variable Set but getting Fatal Error when installing

Tags: software-installation, display

Display Variable Set, Xclock is opening.. but when installing i am getting below issue,

```
oracle@training ODI]$ pwd
/u01/app/oracle/ODI
[oracle@training ODI]$ export DISPLAY=:0
[oracle@training ODI]$ xhost +
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
[oracle@training ODI]$ 
[oracle@training ODI]$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
[oracle@training ODI]$ cd /u01/app/oracle/ODI/;/opt/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/java -jar fmw_12.2.1.2.0_infrastructure.jar
Launcher log file is /tmp/OraInstall2019-05-09_11-42-00PM/launcher2019-05-09_11-42-00PM.log.
Extracting the installer . . . . . . . . . . Done
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: You have loaded library /tmp/orcl8221132109316816964.tmp/Disk1/install/linux/libjni.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Checking if CPU speed is above 300 MHz.   Actual 2904.002 MHz    Passed
Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors.   Actual 16777216    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 512 MB.   Actual 6015 MB    Passed
Checking if this platform requires a 64-bit JVM.   Actual 32    Passed (64-bit not required)
Checking temp space: must be greater than 300 MB.   Actual 21275 MB    Passed

Preparing to launch the Oracle Universal Installer from /tmp/OraInstall2019-05-09_11-42-00PM
Log: /tmp/OraInstall2019-05-09_11-42-00PM/install2019-05-09_11-42-00PM.log
X-Server access is denied on host
[Fatal Error] DISPLAY variable set incorrectly: :0
[Resolution] Verify that your DISPLAY environment variable is set correctly, 
and that there is an X11 server on the system. If you are 
running the Oracle Installer as a different user or on a different host, 
you may need to use the xhost command to ensure that host/user 
has permission to write to your display.


The log(s) can be found here: /tmp/OraInstall2019-05-09_11-42-00PM.
[oracle@training ODI]$
```

Comment: What was `$DISPLAY` set to before you set it to `:0`? Why did you set it in the first place if other X clients are working? What is your environment (are you, for example, running this on a local machine on which you have a graphical desktop)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. What operating system are you using? If Linux, which one? What are you trying to install? Are you running a graphical environment? Are you physically in front of the machine or are you connecting remotely? If remotely, how are you connecting? The more information you give us, the better the chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Hi Kusalananda,                                                                                                  
Thanks for  helping me out. DISPLAY variable is same before too. I have tried with somany combination. For my case XCLOCK is working well.